# A singleton class creation with factory method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

My singleton class  implements a interface and in future I can expect many concrete implementation to come out .
I am thinking of creating an instance of this class through factory method. factory method may be overloaded .
My question is how good or bad this idea is ?

Comment: This question is subjective. Do you have a specific question / scenario in mind ?

Comment: @DeepakBala  I am writing a abstraction over a persistence mechanism for my system .Say XMLPersistence.I want to pass a single reference of this class  to every calling subsystem.I also know that in future I may have to move to another implementation of this class but again single instance thing remain constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is irrelevant if the instance returned from your factory method is a singleton. That is an implementation choice - do what is correct for your need.

Also, if your method signature is returning an interface, then technically it's an [*abstract* factory](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) method, not a [factory](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated comment, sure you can do that. A factory method dishes out singleton implementations of your persistence classes based on the overloaded parameters or an enum / integer value in the parameter. There are many frameworks out there that use this pattern, say to give you instances of a client that communicate with a server based on different protocols.

```
MyFactory.pbClient("host", port);
MyFactory.httpClient("host", port);
```